# awesome nested set order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, treeview, awesome-nested-set

Im using the [awesome nested set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) plugin for ruby on rails.   How do I go about sorting by like :name column or something ?

Currently shows the tree like

```
A
- C
- B
```

I want it like

```
A
- B
- C
```

Comment: This has been updated now with :order_column , thanks to @askrynnikov for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already implemented in [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)

> order_column: on which column to do sorting, by default it is the
>   left_column_name. Example: acts_as_nested_set :order_column =>
>   :position

and [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree)

> If you want a specific order, add a new integer column to your model in a >migration:

```
t.integer :sort_order
```

> and in your model:

```
class OrderedTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_closure_tree order: 'sort_order'
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to trigger such a sort just once and for a subtree?

Comment: I'm not sure if this was what was intended by the question, because the example was slightly ambiguous. If the parent category is named 'Z', then using ```order_column => :position``` will yield the lis with the parent at the bottom. If the goal is to have each level alphabetized, with each category's children alphabetized *within that category* then order_column won't work (unless you add a column for a specific order and manage that to be alphabetized with a whole bunch of other methods/code).

Answer (score 7):

Doing this overrides the database sort:

```
@item.children.except(:order).order("your_sort_column")
```

Example:

```
organization.self_and_descendants.to_sql
=> "SELECT `organizations`.* FROM `organizations`  WHERE (`organizations`.`lft` >= 1 AND `organizations`.`lft` < 54) ORDER BY `organizations`.`lft`" 

organization.self_and_descendants.except(:order).order("organization_nm").to_sql
=> "SELECT `organizations`.* FROM `organizations`  WHERE (`organizations`.`lft` >= 1 AND `organizations`.`lft` < 54) ORDER BY organization_nm"
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's impossible now.
In their class written that "odering by an other column than lft does not work" (lib/awesome_nested_set.rb)

Comment: 2 and a bit years later, this seems to still be the case?

Comment: what about 3 years later?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to do a database sort with this: @item.children.except(:order).order("your_sort_column")

Comment: In my opinion, not implement position behavior is like create bike without pedals. You can ride, but not so much :D What guys you are using for standart website navigation? It seems there is no decision in Rails with tree behavior and positions.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm what @kr00lix said.
My way to bypass that problem :

```
@item_children = @item.children
@item_children = @item_children.sort_by!(&:your_sort_column)
```

But I agree that in order to avoid useless memory consumption, it would be much nicer to set the order in the SQL command directly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in Rails with recursion:

```
def add_self_and_children
  [self, children.sort_by{|e| e.name}.map{|c| c.add_self_and_children}].flatten
end
```

Then call `Model.root.add_self_and_children`.

But obviously this involves a series of massive database hits.

So if someone who knows more about SQL recursion than I wants to convert this to pure SQL, that would be magic!

BTW, for some reason the following, which would have been a little kinder on the database, did not work:

```
def add_self_and_children
  [self, children.order(:name).map{|c| c.add_self_and_children}].flatten
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Eight years later, I spend a day screwing around with this and this still seemed to be the easiest way to alphabetize each tier within its parent category. Sucks that a more performant option isn't readily available yet.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing Steven_Noble's answer a couple weeks ago, I finally had time to come back and refactor this to a solution that doesn't create N database hits. I added the below method to my nested set model (e.g. Category):

```
  def sorted_heir_list(target = self, set = self.descendants)
    sorted_list = [target]
    kids = set.select{|i| i.parent_id == target.id}.sort_by{|j| j.name}
    kids.each do |k|
      sorted_list.concat(sorted_heir_list(k, set))
    end
    sorted_list
  end
```

It's still recursive and a bit verbose, and can probaby be improved a bit further, but now you can call `category.sorted_heir_list` and get a flat array of options sorted by name, while retaining the heirarchy. Useful for dropdown select options!

NB: I used `kids` instead of `children` specifically to avoid confusion with the child functions defined in awesome_nested_set.